# How to delete multiple frames in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, image-processing

I am building an image processing methods GUI in that I have created some frames to show various methods in each frame as a tab using the notebook functionality of the Tkinter. How can I create a function that deletes all four frames, so that when I import the second image the first one will be removed and the newly imported image is added to the frames?

I have tried the winfo_children function to destroy frames but it only works for one frame at a time. I also tried looping through all frames. my skills are not sufficient to think through this one. So, I need a suggestion or anything that I m missing.

Thank you so much for your time any help is appreciated.

```
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab4 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='Imported Image')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Method 1')
tabControl.add(tab3, text='Method 2')
tabControl.add(tab4, text='Method 3')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

frame1_title=  tk.Label(tab1,bd=10)
frame1_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

frame2_title=  tk.Label(tab2, font='times 35')
frame2_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

frame3_title=  tk.Label(tab3,font='times 35')  
frame3_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `winfo_children` to do this.

```
for tab in tabControl.winfo_children():
    for child in tab.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
```

`winfo_children` returns a list of child widgets. The outer loop gets all the tab frames, then the inner loop destroys the tab contents of each frame.
**Edit**
To not delete the canvas, you can use the `isinstance` function. This will check if the widget is a canvas and will only destroy it if it is not.

```
for tab in tabControl.winfo_children():
    for child in tab.winfo_children():
        if not isinstance(child, tk.Canvas):
            child.destroy()
```

Comment: Hi yes, I have used it but it only destroys one frame. I have no single frame I have multiple frames in tabs. That is if I destroy tabs then the GUI will be of no use.

Comment: Do you want to destroy the tabs, or the contents of the tabs?

Comment: I want to delete contents in tabs because if I delete tabs only the GUI with a big box is visible. I cannot import images if I delete the tabs.                              The format I am using is I have three tabs and in those three tabs, I have three frames. Now I want to delete the contents in all three frames. These three frames are not inside each other but they are individual like each frame in each tab. for ex: tab1 contains frame 1 , tab 2 contains frame 2 like that. I hope this clears the confusion